# the transition matrix between dominating vectors is doubly stochastic?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vectors $X,Y$ of length $n$ with non-negative entries, we call $X$ dominates $Y$ if $X_1+\cdots+X_k\ge Y_1+\cdots +Y_k$ for each $k=1,\dots, n$ and $X_1+\cdots+X_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$.

I heard one claim stating that there exists a [doubly stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) $A$ such that $Y=AX$.

I am wondering how to prove this claim?

Comment: Is "dominating" the same as [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization)? That is, are we meant to presume that $X_1 \geq \cdots \geq X_n$ in this context?

Comment: If so, then this result is proved in Theorem II.1.10 of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that the definition of $X$ "dominating" $Y$ is exactly the same as the [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) $x \succ y$. This would make particular sense given that $x \succ y$ if and only if there exists a stochastic matrix $A$ for which $y = Ax$.

The following proof is adapted from Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*. We begin by introducing $T$ transform. A $T$-transform is the linear map given by
$$
Tx = (x_1,\dots,x_{j-1},tx_j + (1-t)x_k, x_{j+1},\dots,x_{k-1},(1-t)x_j + tx_k, x_{k+1},\dots,x_n).
$$
Notably, the matrix associated with this linear map is doubly stochastic. We now prove the following claim:

> **Claim:** If $x \succ y$, then there exists a finite sequence of $T$-transforms $T_1,\dots,T_m$ such that $y = T_m\cdots T_2T_1 x$.

*Proof of Claim:* This is easy to see for $n = 2$. For general $n$, we proceed by induction. Assume that the statement holds up to $n-1$, and take $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$ with $x \succ y$. Since transpositions are $T$-transforms, every permutation is a product of finitely many transpositions, and $x,y$ can each be sorted in descending order using permutation matrices, we can assume without loss of generality that $x_1 \geq \cdots \geq x_n$ and $y_1 \geq \cdots \geq y_n$.

We know that $x_n \leq y_1 \leq x_1$. Select $k$ such that $x_k \leq y_1 \leq x_{k-1}$. Then $y_1 = tx_1 + (1 - t)x_k$ for some $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Let $T_1$ denote the $T$-transform given by
$$
T_1 z = (tz_1 + (1 - t)z_k, \dots, (1 - t) z_1 + tz_k , \dots), \quad z \in \Bbb R^n.
$$
Note that the first coordinate of $T_1x$ is $y_1$. Let
$$
x' = ([T_1x]_2,\dots,[T_1x]_n),\\
y' = (y_2,\dots,y_n).
$$
Note that $x' \succ y'$. Indeed, we have
$$
x_1 \geq \cdots \geq x_{k-1} \geq y_1 \geq y_2 \geq \cdots \geq y_n,
$$
which means that for $2 \leq m \leq k-1$ we have
$$
\sum_{j=2}^m x_j \geq \sum_{j=2}^m y_j.
$$
For $k \leq m \leq n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^m x_j' &= \sum_{k=2}^{k-1} x_j + [(1 - t)x_1 + tx_k] + \sum_{j=k+1}^m x_j
\\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^m x_j - tx_1 + (t - 1)x_k
\\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^m x_j - y_1
\\ & \geq 
\sum_{j=1}^m y_j - y_1 = \sum_{j=2}^m y_2.
\end{align}
$$
The $\geq$ in the last line  is an equality when $m = n$ since $x \succ y$. Thus, $x' \succ y'$. So, by the inductive hypothesis, there exist a finite number of $T$-transforms so that $y' = (T_r\cdots T_2)x'$. If we regard these as $T$-transforms on $\Bbb R^n$ by stipulating that they leave the first coordinate fixed, then we have
$$
(T_r \cdots T_1)x = (T_r \cdots T_2)(y_1,x') = (y_1,y') = y. \quad \square.
$$

With the claim proved, it suffices to note that each $T$-transform corresponds to a doubly-stochastic matrix and that the product of doubly stochastic matrices is necessarily doubly stochastic.

So, if we find a series of matrices $T_1,\dots,T_r$ that correspond to $T$-transforms such that $y = T_r \cdots T_1 x$, then we can take
$$
A = T_r \cdots T_1,
$$
which is doubly stochastic.